# Inserting multiple rows into the sql database in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

How I can insert multiple rows in sql statement in the php. It seems the array does not work. Some of my variables are in array and some are fixed in the loop.

```
$sql = array();
    for ($i=0; $i< count($datesArray); $i++){
        array_push($sql, "INSERT INTO courseSchedule (isc, date, startTime, endTime, sessionTitle, sessionDescription) VALUES ('$isc', '$datesArray[$i]', '$TimesArrayStart[$i]', '$TimesArrayEnd[$i]', '$TitlesArray[$i]', '$DescriptionsArray[$i]')");
    }
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
```

I have changed the code something like this, but still no entry.

```
$sql = array();
for ($i=0; $i< count($datesArray); $i++){
    $sqlarray[] = '('.$isc.', '.$datesArray[$i].', '.$TimesArrayStart[$i].', '.$TimesArrayEnd[$i].', '.$TitlesArray[$i].', '.$DescriptionsArray[$i].')';
}
$sql = 'INSERT INTO courseSchedule (isc, date, startTime, endTime, sessionTitle, sessionDescription) VALUES'.implode(',', $sqlarray);
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
```

Using mysqli_multi_query also doesn't work:

```
 $sql   = "";
$count = count($datesArray);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
    $sql .= "INSERT INTO courseSchedule (isc, date, startTime, endTime, sessionTitle, sessionDescription) VALUES ('$isc', '$datesArray[$i]', '$TimesArrayStart[$i]', '$TimesArrayEnd[$i]', '$TitlesArray[$i]', '$DescriptionsArray[$i]')";
}
echo($sql);
$query = mysqli_multi_query($db_conx, $sql);
```

Comment: For mysql_multi_query, you need to add ';' at final of each query. By the way, my second solution is more efficient to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines should work - in fact, this should work.

Untested, but quickly wrote it from my work desk, in stealth mode.

```
$sql   = 'INSERT INTO courseSchedule (isc, date, startTime, endTime, sessionTitle, sessionDescription) VALUES ';
$count = count($datesArray);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count); $i++)
{
    $sql .= "('$isc', '$datesArray[$i]', '$TimesArrayStart[$i]', '$TimesArrayEnd[$i]', '$TitlesArray[$i]', '$DescriptionsArray[$i]')" . (($i + 1) == $count ? '' : ',');
}
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
```

Comment: what is this statement st the end of $sql for? (($i + 1) == $count ? '' : ',' =====> I got it. I won't put a , at the end.

Comment: I tried this code. I echoed the $sql and it seems it is okay but nothing inserts into the table. With one row it works, but multiple rows doesn't.

Comment: Have you verified the id you're connecting to the MySQL db has the correct GRANT access to write?

Comment: I am not sure what your point is. But I checked without a for loop just insert one row, everything is okay. But multiple values in the sql statement does not work to insert multiple rows. It's strange here. Everything and the code seems okay but can't catch it what is wrong.

Comment: Problem solved. There was a restriction in the table with fk which did not allow to all multiple rows with the same id of a column.

Answer (score 2):

Concatenate queries and use mysqli_multi_query(). Note that you need to end SQL Statement with **;**

Take a look http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Or, for INSERT, you can build you query like this:

```
INSERT INTO example
  (example_id, name, value, other_value)
VALUES
  (100, 'Name 1', 'Value 1', 'Other 1'),
  (101, 'Name 2', 'Value 2', 'Other 2'),
  (102, 'Name 3', 'Value 3', 'Other 3'),
  (103, 'Name 4', 'Value 4', 'Other 4');
```

Answer (score 0):

By process of elimination AND because you don't show us your table, since your PHP for syntax is correct and your INSERT is correct, it's obvious you don't have values for each value (that can't be NULL) in your INSERT. Maybe you should echo those values before the for to verify. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually echo all variables and all are not null during the insert process.